# how to prevent access to other user with same user id (UID)

Tags: permissions, users, dual-boot

I have two Linux OS installed in two partitions in my system. However I have few usernames which are common in both partitions. For ex, I have user `friend` in both the OS.

I have noticed that `friend` in one OS has access to the files of `friend` in other OS.

Is this expected ? These two `friend` account in two OS are different account (co-incidentally with same username).

If this is expected then is there a way to prevent this type of access granted just because they have same username? I don't want the files of `friend` of OS1 to be accessible to `friend` of OS2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have the partitions mountable to each other; one way to prevent cross-OS access would be to prevent this cross-mounting. Another way is to ensure that each account has a different UID. The UID is what matters, not the login name.

Comment: I verified that it is the UID that matters. I think i need to ask a new question to ask how to prevent the cross-mounting. But I need to do the cross-mounting now, so maybe some other time.